# How to get unique pairs of values in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

Given a pySpark DataFrame, how can I get all possible unique combinations of columns `col1` and `col2`.

I can get unique values for a single column, but cannot get unique pairs of `col1` and `col2`:

```
df.select('col1').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
```

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
df.select(['col1','col2']).distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
```

Comment: What error do you get.?

Comment: @Suresh: I do not get any error. I just don't get the unique pairs of values, e.g. `<20; 50>, <30,50>`. instead of it I get unique values of columns, e.g. `20, 50, 30`.

Comment: try this, df.select(['col1','col2']).distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: (r[0],r[1])).collect()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one I tried,

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2),(1,3),(1,2),(2,3)],['col1','col2'])
>>> df.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   2|
|   1|   3|
|   1|   2|
|   2|   3|
+----+----+

>>> df.select('col1','col2').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r:r[0]).collect() ## your mapping
[1, 2, 1]
>>> df.select('col1','col2').distinct().show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   3|
|   2|   3|
|   1|   2|
+----+----+
>>> df.select('col1','col2').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r:(r[0],r[1])).collect() 
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this function below:

```
    `df[['col1', 'col2']].drop_duplicates()`
```